# Getting the user's timezone in fulfillment

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm using Dialogflow alongside the Actions on Google and I'm looking to save content to a database with the date as they key.

Is there a way to get the user's correct timezone date? I don't want to request location permission. I've tested other actions that haven't requested the permissions and are using dates properly, so there must be a way.

Can I ask the user to specify a date as an entity? Will that provide the local time zone? It's an extra step from the user but if it would tell the correct time then I'll do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to get a user's timezone without getting their location, or by explicitly asking them for their timezone.

Comment: Do we know why this is the case?  I'm trying to build an appointment system and when a fulfillment sends the user a list of slots that are open, I need those to be in the user's local timezone ... that appears to mean that the webhook needs to know the timezone of the user.